# How to trigger PowerShell script if Azure App service instance fails

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-appservice

Hi I have PowerShell script which grabs azure app service instances one by one and invokes URLS. I run this script using azure devops.

I want my scripts to get triggered every time if any of app service instance gets sick and gets replaced It should run the script again for New App service instance

I don't know how to trigger script in real time , I tried to search which landed me to azure automation runbook but did not find anything for app instance failure.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not completely sure about when you want to trigger your script. When a new version of the application is deployed to any of app services, or when the health of any app services is disturbed?

Comment: @Tomasz I want to trigger my script when the health of any app services is disturbed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Azure Monitor Rules. This will monitor health of your app and trigger action of your choice when something will be not ok. Add a condition with HealtCheck:

[image]

Then assign action group that triggers Azure Funcion with powershell script.

[image]

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-log